Where did the questions go?
Over the last two weeks, there have been very few questions. Where did they go? We haven't asked all the questions about LEGO, we never will! 

This may be less of a question (maybe) and more of an announcement, but...
If everyone who sees this sentence asks a good question, the community will come back!


The irony that this question remains unviewed and unanswered is sickening.

It's not just that the Questions are gone (though there was a bit of an influx the last few days), also the upvotes and answer approvals are not what they used to be. I spent some time and effort on a few of them with very little response. Almost feels like @CalebWoodman and I are the only two active members :)

Yep. As much as I'd hate to see this place go, I think we're far into burninatable territory.

Not anymore! Feels good.
